How can i replicate this?
I'm using the Tabs widget from the Crocoblock JetTabs Plugin in Elementor and I have this
JetTabs Tabs Example
The middle bar is a border of each of the Tabs Control Item and the "Active" state makes it change colo
What I want is to replicate the animation of this gif
https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExOGw3Z3Jsem5mcDl6bnl2NDJqcWRoajdvaXlmN2lxZzhwYXNwbnRnZyZlcD12MV9pbnRlcm5hbF9naWZfYnlfaWQmY3Q9Zw/17TaE4JtW10uFCZDr1/source.gif
There you can see how when you click on one of the tabs, the middle bar, instead of simply changing color, you can see how the color moves in a smooth animation
I just want to recreate that animation, I already have the rest covered
